# Filtering array of functions Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

When I filter an Array of Functions to exclude a specific function from the array, the filtered array contains no elements. Any idea of why this is happening?

```
var array: [()->()] = []

array.append(function1)
array.append(function2)

let function: ()
function = function1()
var filteredArray: [()->()] = []
filteredArray = array.filter { $0() != function }

print(filteredArray.count) // 0
```

Comment: Void (empty tuple) it is not a function. Btw `()->()` it is not `Equatable`

Comment: is that not how to create an array that holds functions? and would just () be equatable?

Comment: () is the result of a function that does not return any value. An empty tuple also know as Void. The array declaration is correct. function = function1() will assign the result of function1 to function which is Void. All your functions in your array returns Void (doesn't return anything same as an empty tuple). `$0()` will execute the function code and return `Void` therefore all elements are equal to `function` which is `Void` thats why it return an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-Nominal Types cannot be filtered. This is because they are not equatable:

**i.e.** Here are some Non-Nominal Types

- `Any`
- `Tuples` - [soon to be equatable](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0283-tuples-are-equatable-comparable-hashable.md)
- `Void aka () aka Empty Tuple`
- `Functions aka () -> ()`

What you could do is create a struct like so:

```swift
struct Method: Hashable, Equatable {
    var name: String
    var method: () -> () // or whatever type you want
    init(_ n: String,_ m: @escaping () -> ()) {
        name = n
        method = m
    }

    // Equatable
    static func == (lhs: Method, rhs: Method) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    // Hashable
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}
```

So that the `name` is what checks if methods are equal. But so much for `structs`.

If you wanted, you could make a similar `class` instead to keep track of the reference.

---

Example code:

```swift
func function1() {print("foo")}
func function2() {print("bar")}

var array: [Method] = []

array.append(Method("One", function1))
array.append(Method("Two", function2))

let function: Method
function = Method("One", function1)
var filteredArray: [Method] = []
filteredArray = array.filter { $0 != function}

print(filteredArray.count) // 1

filteredArray.first?.method() // prints "bar"
```

Comment: if your `Method` struct is equatable `{ $0.name != function.name }` is redundant `{ $0 != function }`

Comment: when I try to append the method to the array I get an error "extra argument in call" and a warning "Initialization of 'Method' (aka 'OpaquePointer') results in a dangling pointer"

Comment: @stepjesse I just fixed a bug in the code, so that should do the trick. Please respond if it still doesn't work.

Comment: took me some time to implement it into my game correctly but it works perfectly thank you!